# Download directly from firebase function temp folder

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm wondering if it is possible and safe to download a file directly from firebase functions temp folder? I have a firebase function that generates a pdf file in the temp folder when triggered from the app (e.g. via `httpsCallable`). Is it possible for the app user to directly download the generated pdf file from the temp folder or does the function needs to do the extra step of saving the file in firebase storage before download? I have not seen examples of the former. In my case there is no need to save the pdf file once it has been downloaded so I see no point in uploading it to storage if it is possible to download it straight from temp folder.

Comment: Yes you can absolutely download the PDF from the temp folder as a response from the Functions call.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the app user to directly download the generated pdf file from the temp folder

No, it is not possible.  The /tmp filesystem is only accessible to the server instance that created it, and it resides fully in memory in that instance.  It's not directly accessible anywhere outside that.

> does the function needs to do the extra step of saving the file in firebase storage before download?

If you want to save the file to Cloud Storage, you will need to use a Cloud Storage SDK to upload the file there.  This is not an optional step - you will eventually lose that in-memory content if you don't save it somewhere persistent.

Comment: Thank you Doug, I suspected this is the case but was not 100% sure.

Comment: "The /tmp filesystem is only accessible to the server instance that created it" so after the function is done then /tmp folder is emptied automatically? Because here  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#always_delete_temporary_files I found that I have to do it manually, but can't find anywhere how to do it.

Comment: @jeand'arme Do whatever you would normally do in nodejs to delete files.  There is nothing special about deleting files in Cloud Functions.